# How to save TextBox content in a file

Tags: c#

So I am aware that `SaveFile()` method work for `RichTextBox` like below:

```
richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

But its not works for `TextBox`

```
textBox1.SaveFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
```

I want to save `TextBox` text into a file. How can I do that ? 
All ideas and alternatives are appreciated :)

Comment: If you *get an error*, you can include the **exact** error message in your question. It's right on the screen in front of you; there is absolutely no reason for you to fail to include it in your post. We can't see your screen from where we are. You have that information, and you're asking us for free help to solve *your problem*. The very least you can do is provide information that's right in front of your eyes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for `textbox`

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, textBox1.Text);
```